# How can you tell what method a constraint was created with in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints

There are two ways to create a constraint,

**Method A:**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.<tablename> ADD CONSTRAINT
<namingconventionconstraint> UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
<columnname>
```

**Method B:**

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
<namingconventionconstraint> ON dbo.<tablename>
(
<columnname>
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

However, it appears that these constraints need to be dropped using a method that is dependent on how they were created (Drop constraint vs drop index). Is there a way to determine what method the constraint was created other than trying a method and seeing if it fails? I know you can have SQL Server create a drop script for you but I'm looking for a query of some sort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- A unique constraint will appear in [sys.objects with type = UQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)
- A unique index will *not* appear in sys.objects
- Both appear in [sys.indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx)

This is why you can have the same index name for many table, but a table level unique constraint has to be database/schema unique

Comment: The database I am currently dealing with this issue in has both unique constraints and unique indexes prefixed with UQ, will it still be different in sys.objects?

**edit** I realized thats a poorly worded question. If I look at the indexes folder under each table in SQL Server Management Studio they are prefixed with UQ. Will their type still be different when looking at sys.objects?

Comment: @stocherilac: A unique index entry (method B) won't exist in sys.objects